# Binary Search Trees and Sorting(and other basic algorithms), is the code written in C# and Java almost interchangable?

Tags: c#, java, algorithm

I am trying to implement Binary Search Trees and Sorting algorithms,(and other basic algorithms), I want to first implement them in C#. I haven't learned Java at the moment. My question is, for those basic algorithms and data structures, is the code written in C# and Java almost interchangeable? Because the basic syntax of C# and Java are the same, and implementing those basic algorithms and data structures just needs to use a subset of the language(C# and Java), which should be almost the same.

Is this right? Or what do I need to take care when I try to transfer my algorithms code from C#(C# classes) to Java(Java classes) in the future(after I learn Java)?

Comment: syntax would probably differ.!

Comment: The code will be very similar indeed. I once ported 20K C# lines into Java, and that took like 3 hours, spent mostly around I/O. So worry not.

Comment: so how did you port? scan C# code line by line and change those I/O statements to Java ones?

Comment: i just renamed the files to .java and compiled, got 500 errors. Change "substring" to "Substring", was down to 375. Etc. Granted, i was somewhat following Java concepts to begin with - one class per file, files named same as classes, same deal with packages etc.

Comment: great, thanks for sharing your experience. I might follow the same process later :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they are extremely similar for most operations. Though there are some pitfalls, you could for example be using an API that has no Java counterpart, or maybe you consistantly have used the "var" keyword instead of specifying a datatype (Java has no such thing!).

Furthermore, even though it might be similar, it might not be optimised for the language. Sometimes a language can do the same thing as another one in much fewer lines of code.

But for a binary search tree / sorting algorithms, you should be fine. I can't think of any complications for those actually (apart from 'var' perhaps)

Comment: How about those data structures? will the C# classes be almost the same as those Java classes? For example, lists.

Comment: Mhm, not entirely but they are more or less alike. Depend which List you want to use, whilst in C# you might just use List<T> you need to use ArrayList<T> in Java :)

Answer (score 0):

If you stick with just basic language constructions such as loops, conditions etc., it should be quite simple to convert C# to Java. It might be also doable with some automatic tools.

However, you should avoid using some complex library functions from .NET. Using Math class should be fine, I bet Java has something similar, but some others may not be directly available in Java.

Comment: so if I avoid using some complex library functions from .NET, then my C# classes would almost be the same as the target Java classes, right?

Comment: I assume that. Algorithms that you gave as examples are quite straightforward and mostly based on math so their representation should be similar in both languages.